# Fillna with sum of previous row and the change in another column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame which has some `nan` values. I want to fill them by adding the previous row with the change in the column `Factor`. The dataframe looks like this:

```
        Value Col    Factor
2022-11-30  0.020       84
2022-12-31  0.015       77
2023-01-31  NaN         90
2023-02-28  NaN         44
2023-03-31  NaN         39
```

To fill `df.iloc[2, 0]`, I want to sum `df.iloc[1,0]` and the change in `Factor` column(in that case which is 90-77 = 13). The expected output is like this:

```
        Value Col    Factor
2022-11-30  0.020       84
2022-12-31  0.015       77
2023-01-31  13.015      90
2023-02-28  59.015      44
2023-03-31  64.015      39
```

I tried with for loop, it works. But could not find a way which is pandas function but fill the nans row by row. I used `df['Factor'].diff(1)` to get the difference of the `Factor` column but do not know how to fill these nans row by row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a masked [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['Value Col'] = (
df['Factor'].diff()
 .abs()
 .where(df['Value Col'].isna())
 .cumsum()
 .add(df['Value Col'].ffill(), fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
            Value Col  Factor
2022-11-30      0.020      84
2022-12-31      0.015      77
2023-01-31     13.015      90
2023-02-28     59.015      44
2023-03-31     64.015      39
```

Comment: It works!. Want to add one thing that, the `abs()` is not necessary here. I also want to accept negative change. One question, as per pandas documentation, cumsum works along with all the columns. But how this code valid if the dataframe have multiple other columns too?

Comment: @EMT here we're using the `Series` method, so there is only one column. If you want to use a DataFrame you have to slice the multiple columns and ensure all are aligned. It depends if you have one or multiple factors

Answer (score 2):

I think above answer should be modified to use groupby

So I made a example again

**example**

```
data = {'Date': {0: '2022-11-30', 1: '2022-12-31', 2: '2023-01-31', 
                 3: '2023-02-28', 4: '2023-03-31', 5: '2023-04-30', 6: '2023-05-31'}, 
        'Value Col': {0: 0.02, 1: 0.015, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: 0.01, 6: None}, 
        'Factor': {0: 84, 1: 77, 2: 90, 3: 44, 4: 39, 5: 19, 6: 49}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    Date      Value Col Factor
0   2022-11-30  0.020   84
1   2022-12-31  0.015   77
2   2023-01-31  NaN     90
3   2023-02-28  NaN     44
4   2023-03-31  NaN     39
5   2023-04-30  0.010   19
6   2023-05-31  NaN     49
```

---

need grouper for making group

```
gr = df['Value Col'].notna().cumsum()
```

`gr`

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
```

---

**Code**

cumsum & ffill and so on by groupby

```
df['Value Col'] = (df['Factor']
                   .groupby(gr).diff().abs()
                   .groupby(gr).cumsum()
                   .add(df['Value Col'].ffill(), fill_value=0))
```

`df`

```
    Date      Value Col Factor
0   2022-11-30  0.020   84
1   2022-12-31  0.015   77
2   2023-01-31  13.015  90
3   2023-02-28  59.015  44
4   2023-03-31  64.015  39
5   2023-04-30  0.010   19
6   2023-05-31  30.010  49
```